# Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate not returning correct model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an issue I've not seen before with the Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate not returning the correct model in the callback.

Here's the code:

```
    var id = args._id;
    var updateObj = {updatedDate: Date.now()};
    _.extend(updateObj, args);

    Model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, updateObj, function(err, model) {
        if (err) {
            logger.error(modelString +':edit' + modelString +' - ' + err.message);
            self.emit('item:failure', 'Failed to edit ' + modelString);
            return;
        }
        self.emit('item:success', model);
    });
```

The original document in the db looks like this:

```
{
    _id: 1234
    descriptors: Array[2],
    name: 'Test Name 1'
}
```

The updateObj going in looks like this:

```
{
    _id: 1234
    descriptors: Array[2],
    name: 'Test Name 2'
}
```

The model returned from the callback is identical to the original model, not the updatedObj.
If I query the db, it has been updated correctly.  It's just not being returned from the database.

This feels like a 'stupid-user' error, but I can't see it.  Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: That is an awesome spot.  And a reminder why I need to keep all my projects matching on versions, as that package was passing it's own unit tests.  Thank you.

Answer (score 395, accepted):

In Mongoose 4.0, the default value for the `new` option of `findByIdAndUpdate` (and `findOneAndUpdate`) has changed to `false`, which means returning the old doc (see #2262 of the [release notes](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/wiki/4.0-Release-Notes#backwards-breaking-changes)). So you need to explicitly set the option to `true` to get the new version of the doc, after the update is applied:

```
Model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, updateObj, {new: true}, function(err, model) {...
```

Comment: Also got caught out by the changes to the return values of the 'create' method.  Cheers buddy, I'd up-vote twice if I could.

Comment: Also put in a PR for updated docs on the mongoose project, so hopefully it won't catch anyone else out.

Comment: Oh boy thank you @JohnnyHK. This wrecked me.  Of course I want the new one back.  More consistent with the API maybe, but not really with common sense... if I update something I'd like to see the changes. Thanks mongoose...

Comment: Wow! What a horrible decision they made! That is the only point of doing the find in the first place instead of update.

Comment: This has been a very useful answer!

Comment: I do not understand why someone would rather have the old document in the response instead of the new

Comment: Thanks for this. While I can understand why people might want both, it seems like `true` should be the default.

Comment: The blame is on Mongo which define it as `false`. Mongoose just tries to be consistent with Mongo.

Comment: Such a ridiculous default setting.

Comment: Would I use findByIdAndUpdate to update a field that exists all documents in a collection for a specific ObjectId no matter how deeply nested the field is?

Comment: Is this because at database level it's costly to return the updated object instead of the old one?

Comment: Wow this is so silly, I've been working on it for 2 days trying to figure out why my table is not updating with new value.

Comment: writing a document into a database and reading it from the database are two separate operations. It already has the original document due to it needing to merge in the new changes, so that one's free, already retrieved. To then get the new document from the database is another operation. So there is a cost difference.

Comment: To add to what @user2087941 said, the default behaviour is in fact correct, even though it might not seem like it at first.

It is a performance optimisation because you can simply merge your old data with the update object and return that. This way, you don't have to do an unnecessary query to DB. In a nutshell:


response.json({ ...oldDocumentReturnedByTheUpdate, ...updateObject })

Comment: I wasted 6 hours figuring out what mistake I was making 

Answer (score 0):

```
app.put("/vendor/:id", async (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.params)
    await ModelName.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { type: change }, function (err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            conslole.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(docs)
        }
    })
})
```

**Example:**

```
app.put("/vendor/:id", async (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.params)
    const data = await userModel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { isVendor: true }, function (err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            conslole.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(docs)
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

findByIdAndUpdate needs { new: true } after you try to update a component of a model or the whole model.

```
 const job = await Job.findByIdAndUpdate(
         jobId,
         {
           images: arrayImages,
         },
          { new: true }
       );
```