# Mongo/Mongoose fast update causes loss of data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to mongo/mongoose and noticed a bug when updating collection. I have this nodejs code:

```
User
    .findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: id }, { $set: params })
    .select('-password')
    .exec(function (error, user) {
      return res.json({ user: user });
    });
```

The code above works perfectly when updating regularly - but when i spam it and send lots of requests the user data returned last does not match with the user data i fetch afterwards with:

```
User.findOne(...)
```

How can i make sure this does not happen and the data returned from the update & the data fetched from `User.findOne(...)` always match?

Thanks

---

EDIT:

I've added the { 'new': true } like so:

```
User
        .findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: id }, { $set: params }, { 'new': true })
        .select('-password')
        .exec(function (error, user) {
          return res.json({ user: user });
        });
```

But still i get different results when i spam update then get the user.

---

EDIT 2

I think i actually need a way to know if the update is done before calling for get on that User. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419575/mongoose-findbyidandupdate-not-returning-correct-model

Comment: @JohnnyHK Although the issue is similar i had no luck with using 'new': true in findByIdAndUpdate

Answer (score 1):

When you spam MongoDB with **lots of writes**, then MongoDB **queues it** in memory and **eventually writes all** data as the resource permits depending on the load and disk performance. You will have to **wait** till all data has been written before trying to read them. If you read the data after some time, you will get correct data. There is an option called `write-concern`, its related to **providing acknowledgement** about the write requests but **does not guarantee** that the write has completed. please check it out: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/write-concern/

By spamming, from my experience I assume that you are issuing multiple write queries using a for loop which is **encountered very little in practical cases**.