# Node.js and MongoDB using Mongoose. Unable to increment doc version using findByIdAndUpdate

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

am currently facing an issue where when two people work on the same page in my angular application they overwrite each other. The issue what I can see is that the doc version doesn't increase thus mongo doesn't check to see if the doc version is newer or older. Can some one guide me on how to fix this. Down below is my code snippet.

```
    var art = new Article(pageBody);
    Article.findByIdAndUpdate(art._id, pageBody, { new: true, upsert: true},{$inc: {art.v: 1 }}, function(err, model) {
      console.log(art.__v);
      // NOTE: new page will never happen here, moved to issue controller
      if (err) {
        err = {
          source: 'Article.findByIdAndUpdate',
          bodyPageId: pageBody._id,
          articleId: art._id,
          message: err.message,
          err: err.toString()
        };
      }
      cb(err);
    });
  } else {
    console.log(art.__v);
    cb();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the update part of your query the context is not the local article instance but the found document so you want to update like this:

```
{ $inc: { v: 1 } }
```

With your current code, MongoDB creates a new subdocument called `"art"` inside your article with a field called `"v"` which is not what you want:

```
{
  art: {
    v: 1
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. It worked out well, but I notice that the function doesn't really have error handling for the version like if let's say you update the model or data it will be v2 but if I also update the model without refreshing it's also v2 but your data has been removed. Any idea how to use Mongodbs built in version control?

Comment: I am not sure I understand...?!

Comment: sorry about that. What I meant was that there is a scenario where I created a cms that users can use to create html pages like for a magazine. Now when two people work on the same page there is not error or warning showing people that their changes are old. What I mean by that is that the versionkey of the first user is 3 and the second user is 1. Since one is less the 3 they should get a error message stating they can't save unless they refresh.

Comment: That sounds more like an application/error handling topic to me. You should be able to build something to support these scenarios nicely based on either a) a check at save-time using the result of your ´findByIdAndUpdate()´ calls (also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30419575/mongoose-findbyidandupdate-not-returning-correct-model) or if you want to go all fancy then b) use Websockets (https://www.dontpanicblog.co.uk/2016/04/17/websocket-push-notifications-with-node-js/) to notify your clients of simultaneous edits to your documents.